# Where is the waypoint in the Warehouses area?

Tags: path-of-exile

I've been looking everywhere, but I can't find it.  However, the area is flagged with a waypoint on the main map...
Note that this area is subdivided into several areas: the warehouse itself and the warehouse sewers (which have multiple levels).  But I can't find the waypoint in any of these area; I must have missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just found it, finally.  Actually, it's not in the warehouses area itself, but in the sewers' last level, right behind the warehouses.

[image: Waypoint location in the Warehouse Sewers]

Comment: I can confirm it is in the sewers of the Warehouse level and not the Warehouse level it self. There should be 2 entrances to the Warehouse sewers in the buildings on Warehouse.

Comment: Note that in World View (U key by default) if you hover over the area it will say that the waypoint is underground even if you haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 0):

For future people searching where the sewers are:

[image]

It's inside one of the houses.

You need to finish the [Lost in Love](http://en.pathofexilewiki.com/wiki/Lost_in_Love) quest for the sewer key.